# Copy/Move Constructor is not called when storing result of overloaded operator+

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I'm trying to figure out the ways when *copy constructor* is called in `c++` but due to compiler optimizations it's really hard for me to figure it out.

Here is the code which I'm  trying to figure it out:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class rectangle
{
public:
   rectangle()
   {
      cout << "Constructor" << endl;
   };
   rectangle(const rectangle& copied){
      cout << "Copy constructor" << endl;
   };
   rectangle operator+(const rectangle& r){
      rectangle temp;
      return temp;
   }
   ~rectangle()
   {
      cout << "Destructor" << endl;
   };
};


int main () {
   rectangle r1;              //constructor
   rectangle r2 = r1;         //copy constructor
   r1 + r2;                    //copy constructor

   //Now let's combine two last one to get two copy constructor:
   rectangle r3 = r1 + r2;    //just one copy constructor;
   return 0;
}
```

1. Instruction `rectangle r1` will call *Constructor* which is ok.
2. Instruction `rectangle r2 = r1` will call *Copy Constructor* which still is understandable.
3. Instruction `r1 + r2`, first call *Constructor* because of `rectangle temp` then calls *Copy Constructor*. so it is not a problem too.
4. **The problem is here** in `rectangle r3 = r1 + r2;` instruction : My expectation is to have following calls:

   - *Constructor* because of `rectangle temp`.
   - *Copy Constructor* because of returning the value of `+` operator.
   - *Copy Constructor* to initialize the `r3` with returned value **but this call is not executed, why?**

Note: to disable the returning optimization of compiler I'm using `-fno-elide-constructors` flag.

**Current Behavior**:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -fno-elide-constructor
$ ./a.out
Constructor
Copy constructor
Constructor
Copy constructor
Destructor
Destructor
Constructor
Copy constructor
Destructor
Destructor
Destructor
Destructor
```

**Expected Behavior:**

```
$ ./a.our
Constructor
Copy constructor
Constructor
Copy constructor
Destructor
Destructor
Constructor
Copy constructor
Copy constructor
Destructor
Destructor
Destructor
Destructor
Destructor
```

Comment: `rectangle r3 = r1 + r2;` is [Copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)  and _"...the initializer expression itself, rather than a temporary materialized from it, is used to initialize the destination object: see [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)..."_

Comment: The copy elision for the construction of `r3` is mandatory since C++17. You cannot suppress it with `-fno-elide-constructors`.

Comment: @user17732522 Thank you! It is really important to point it out that this elision is mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to **return value optimization** aka RVO which is mandatory from C++17.

From [mandatory copy elison documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision):

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are **required to** omit the copy and move construction of class objects, even if the copy/move constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. The objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would otherwise be copied/moved to. The copy/move constructors need not be present or accessible:

> In the initialization of an object, when the initializer expression is a ***prvalue*** of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the variable type...

Now lets apply this to your case. When you wrote

```
rectangle r3 = r1 + r2;
```

The above statement has the following effects in C++17:

1. **Default constructor** will be called/used for the statement `rectangle temp;` inside the overloaded `operator+`. So you will get the output `Constructor`.
2. **Copy constructor** will be called due to the return statement `return temp;` for which you will get the output `Copy constructor`. Thus, a **nameless temporary** is returned to the caller.
3. Now, since the nameless temporary returned in the last step is a **prvalue** and RVO is mandatory from C++17(and so the compiler flag has no effect on RVO), using the above quoted statement that nameless temporary prvalue will be directly used to initialize the object `r3`.

Comment: OP says they are compiling with `-fno-elide-constructors`. Named return value optimization will not be applied.

Comment: @user17732522 NRVO is not mandatory from C++17. On the other hand, RVO is mandatory from C++17. In the [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), the same is mentioned.

Comment: Yes, but OP is asking why the copy construction of `r3` from the return value isn't observed, which is because of the RVO part, not the NVRO part (for which they do observe a constructor call), so the first sentence and quote seem to not fit.

Comment: @user17732522 You are correct. So it would be correct to say that: *"since OP has supplied the no elide flag to the compiler, NRVO will not happen. Which means due to the return expression a **nameless temporary object** will be returned using the copy constructor for which he gets a copy constructor call as shown in the output. But due to mandatory copy elison that nameless temporary prvalue will be directly used to initialize `r3`"*.

Comment: A temporary is created only when a prvalue is converted to a xvalue, which is exactly what the "mandatory copy elision" rules prevent from happening, so that doesn't really seem right. It is more that `r3` is directly initialized from the expression `temp` in the context of the function, which I thought was your intended meaning of the last sentence.

Comment: @user17732522 But `temp` is not nameless and from [rvo](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) *"In the initialization of an object, when the source object is a **nameless** temporary...When the nameless temporary is the operand of a return statement"*. So wouldn't it be more correct/accurate to say that the nameless temporary that was returned due to the return expression `return temp;` is directly used to initialized `r3` because that temporary is nameless and so rvo can applied to it unlike `temp` itself?

Comment: Before C++17 the prvalue was already the temporary, which is what your quote refers to. Since C++17 the prvalue itself is not a temporary, which is exactly what mandatory copy elision means. Now the function call results just in a prvalue and `r3` is initialized by the initializer of that prvalue without an intervening temporary construction (see the second bullet in the upper box of the cppreference link).

Comment: @user17732522 My point is that: *"the prvalue expression(which is different from `temp`) is directly used to initialize `r3` instead of `temp`"*. For this i have created this [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oXMs4HPN7OMLRUyc) that seems to support my claim. Correct me if i am wrong. In the above linked demo, when we call `displayAddress` on `r3` then it prints the same address as the temporary that was created using the copy constructor due to `return temp;` which is different(as can be seen from the address) from `temp`.

Comment: Yes, the address will be the same. I think we only have a disagreement about terminology. In C++17 there is no temporary object. There is only the `r3` object and it is constructed as if the initializer was a xvalue referring to the `temp` object in the function, but `temp` is a different object (if NRVO is not applied). The function call results in a prvalue, but not a temporary.